# Using PHP/MySQL to dynamically load <ul> lists in jQTouch

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, jqtouch

I'm attempting to create a webpage using jQTouch that has the "home" ul list of choices be static, but it will dynamically load the lists as you go farther down the tree.  I'm using this for a car inventory site, where there will be a large chain of pages to load.  I don't want to load all the pages at startup (since it's for mobile devices) so I'm trying to dynamically load my pages and their contents as I go along.

I've got a current page of code working, and tested it on Android 2.1 (works 100% of the time), iPad 4.2.1 (works 90% of the time), and iPod touch 4.2.1 (never works at all).  The important pieces of code are listed below:

index.php:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jqtouch/jqtouch.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="themes/jqt/theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqtouch/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqtouch/jqtouch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQT = $.jQTouch({
      icon: 'cht.png',
      statusBar: 'black',
      slideSelector: 'div#home a'
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function reloadUCD() {
          $('#ucd').load('usedcars.php', function() {
                  return false;
          });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="home">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="edgetoedge">
   <li class="arrow"><a href="#ucd" onClick="reloadUCD();">Search Used Cars</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="ucd">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Used Cars</h1>
    <a class="button back" href="#">Back</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="edgetoedge">
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

usedcars.php is a PHP script that returns MySQL data in the proper form, as below:

```
<div class='toolbar'> 
<h1>Used Cars</h1> 
<a class='button back' href='#'>Back</a> 
</div> 
<ul class='edgetoedge'> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Chevrolet</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Chrysler</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Dodge</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Ford</a></li>   
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>GMC</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Honda</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Hyundai</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Infiniti</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Jeep</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Lincoln</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Nissan</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Toyota</a></li> 
<li class='arrow'><a href='#car'>Volkswagen</a></li> 
</ul>
```

From what I've read on both the jQuery site as well as other threads on stackoverflow, the way I handled the .load function should force it to wait until the .load is completed before letting the onClick continue to the new page.  Given that the Android device is loading it correctly every time makes me think I'm on the right track, but that I'm missing some key issue.

What am I doing wrong with my code to keep it from working 100% of the time on the iPhone/iPt devices?  Is there a different method for the logic I could be using to make it load properly?  Also, is there some bug/problem with jQTouch that would be preventing this from acting right?

Thanks in advance,
Josh Hogan

Comment: What happens when it fails to load?  Do you get any errors on the Safari console?

Comment: I get no errors on the Safari console.  Sorry it took so long to reply -- didn't see the comment :)  Also tested the page on an iPhone 3G running iOS 3.1, it loaded 1st time.  Also loaded correctly on Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: Still don't have an answer to this question -- but it looks like jQTouch isn't what I need to be using.  I'm switching to jQuery Mobile for the website.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this recently. I get an json object from the controller and build my menus from that. In the html I have a "dummy" element (clone) that is hidden, but I clone it create the lists.

HTML:

```
<div id="home" class="current">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="rounded">
    <li class="clone arrow">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.clone').clone().addClass('populate').removeClass('clone')
$('.populate a').html("Bar").attr('id', '#foo')
```